# Unable to pass label in react-select dropdown

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am not able to pass the label value in onChange event handler. Only the value is getting formed. I want to have access to the label. Do help with the same.

handleSelectChange function has access only to the value and not to the label or event of the select dropdown.

```
            <Select name={this.props.name}
                backspaceToRemoveMessage=""
                closeOnSelect={!this.state.stayOpen}
                searchable={false}
                disabled={this.state.disabled}
                multi
                options={this.props.countries}
                simpleValue={true}
                value={this.state.value}
                onChange ={this.handleSelectChange}
            />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because flag `simpleValue=true` parse handler parameter to string of values. Set this flag to `false` and your `handleSelectChange` will have access to array of selected objects. Than you have to generate your value manually. (e.g. `value="one,two"`)

Example of value processing:

```
handleSelectChange = (val) => {
  const value = val.map(item => item.value);
    this.setState({
      value
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can grab element that is selected in the example below in the `updateState`.

**Example**

```
import React from "react";
import Select from 'react-select';

export default class CoolExample extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {value:"foo"};
   }

  updateState(element) {
        this.setState({value: element}); 
  }

  render(){
     var Select = require('react-select'); 
     var options = [
         { value: 'foo', label: 'Foo' },
         { value: 'bar', label: 'Bar' }
     ];

     return(

      <Select
        name="form-field-name"
        value={this.state.value}
        options={options}
        onChange={this.updateState.bind(this)}
      />
   );
  }
}
```